# Nuxtjs brings unexpected token < when importing vue-image-crop-upload library

Tags: vue.js, webpack, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make a cropped image and then upload it to amazon in my `NuxtJs` app. The problem comes when I import library `vue-image-crop-upload` and **get unexpected token <. Or briefly Syntax error**

I tried using `no-ssr` but looks  like a problem inside actual module.

```
                        // Usage in component
                        <no-ssr>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary upload-picture" @click="toggleShow">Cargar imagen</button>
                            <avatar-upload field="img"
                               @crop-success="cropSuccess"
                               v-model="show"
                               :no-square="true"
                               :width="500"
                                lang-type="en"
                               :height="500"
                               :params="params"
                               :headers="headers"
                               img-format="png"></avatar-upload>
                            <img :src="imgDataUrl">
                        </no-ssr>

import VueImageCropUpload from 'vue-image-crop-upload';


                        // Plugin registered
                        import Vue from 'vue';
                        import myUpload from 'vue-image-crop-upload';

                         Vue.component('avatar', myUpload);
                         // nuxt.config.js
                         plugins: [
                           {src: 'plugins/VueCropper', ssr: false},],
                         vendor: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'vue-image-crop-upload'],
```

I expect it working on nuxt.js. Client rendered app on which i tried to do the same works perfect

Comment: Did you solve it ?
and How did you  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding the package to nuxt.js transpile config?

in `nuxt.config.js`

```
  build: {
    transpile: ['vue-image-crop-upload' ]
  }
```